# Angular-Meteor using $state outside of the constructor

Tags: angular-meteor

I'm new to Angular-Meteor. I noticed I could use `$state` in the constructor method (passed as a param), but it won't really work in methods outside of the constructor. What's the correct way of using it (if) outside the constructor method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My technique is to set it equal to a similarly named property on `this`.

As an example:

```
this.$state = $state;
```

Then to access it in the other methods, you can via `this.$state` throughout your class.

Comment: Tried this, I'm still getting `$state is not defined`

Comment: ok, I didn't pass `$state` in export statement, that's why I was getting the error.